# Difficulty with display driver in windows 7. I want to know if i have to change my display driver?

Tags: windows-7, display, intel-graphics

Full information on the specification of the PC:

- Computer: ACPI x64-based PC
- Disk Drive: Toshiba DT01ACA050 ATA Device
- Display Adaptor: AMD Radeon HD 6450
- DVD/CD-ROM drive: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM
- GH24NSBO ATA DEVICE IDE ATA/ATAPI CONTROLLER:
- ATA channel 4
- ATA channel 5
- Intel 7 series/C216 Chipset Family
- SATA AHCI controller- 1E02
- Processor : Intel Core i7-3770 CPU 3.40 GHz

I brought a PC recently. The software detail and hardware details are as above. The computer was showing blue screen error BCcode 2b and a. The problem was with the software of the display adaptor. The software was uninstalled and reinstalled. The problem of blue screen bccode 2b and a is no longer occuring.

However, the display driver is experiencing a showing error.... now The error showed several  time is:

> display driver stopped working and has recovered successfully.

The computer has also experience blue screen error bccode 117.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

> BCCode: 117 = Bug Check 0x117: VIDEO_TDR_TIMEOUT_DETECTED
>
> The VIDEO_TDR_TIMEOUT_DETECTED bug check has a value of 0x00000117.
>   This indicates that the display driver failed to respond in a timely
>   fashion.
>
> Important Info If You Have Received a STOP Code
>
> If you received a blue screen error, or stop code, the computer has
>   shut down abruptly to protect itself from data loss. A hardware
>   device, its driver, or related software might have caused this error.
>   If your copy of Windows came with your computer, call the manufacturer
>   of your computer. If you purchased Windows separately from your
>   computer, Microsoft provides support. To find contact info for
>   Microsoft or your computer manufacturer, Contact Support.
>
> If you have experience with computers and want to try to recover from
>   this error, follow the steps provided in the Microsoft article
>   [Resolving STOP (Blue Screen) Errors in Windows](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=183646).
>
> These actions might prevent an error like this from happening again:
>
> 1. Download and install updates and device drivers for your computer from Windows Update.
> 2. Scan your computer for computer viruses.
> 3. Check your hard disk for errors.
>
> VIDEO_TDR_TIMEOUT_DETECTED Parameters
>
> The following parameters are displayed on the blue screen.
>
> Parameter
>
> Description
>
> 1. The pointer to the internal TDR recovery context, if available.
> 2. A pointer into the responsible device driver module (for example, the owner tag).
> 3. The secondary driver-specific bucketing key.
> 4. Reserved.
>
> Update the Video driver - also look for BIOS and low level chipset
>   drivers at the System Maker's   (motherboard maker's for custom
>   systems).

You can use a product like [Driver Genius](http://www.faultwire.com/products/Driver_Genius_Professional-103.html) or [Radar Sync](http://www.faultwire.com/products/RadarSync-107.html) to verify you have the latest drivers and help keep all your drivers up-to-date. If you're comfortable with driver installations, you can individually find and install current drivers.